# How can I use torch.fft.fft2 to output the same result as troch.fft?

Tags: python, pytorch

In the documentation of pytorch 1.1.0, the description of the return of [`torch.fft`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.1.0/torch.html#torch.fft) is

> "Returns the real and the imaginary part together as an tensor of the same shape input"

In pytorch1.8.1, torch.fft is replaced by [`torch.fft.fft2`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.fft.fft2.html#torch.fft.fft2), and `torch.fft.fft2` outputs the result in complex

For the same data, the output of `torch.fft` is

> tensor([32779.2891]) tensor([67.1836]) tensor([11.9802]) tensor([-47.5729]) tensor([-101.7718]) tensor([-5.7989]) tensor([17.5259]) tensor([41.0830]) tensor([-5.1960]) tensor([42.2860])

The output result of `torch.fft.fft2` is

> tensor(32779.2891+0.j)  tensor(36.2154-25.2860j)  tensor(22.9704-39.8544j) tensor(-62.9149+6.8637j)  tensor(-87.2122-94.2708j)  tensor(-3.2740+52.0396j) tensor(-32.4686+46.9949j)  tensor(-50.1910-30.1725j)  tensor(-8.8877+19.0709j)  tensor(39.9689-32.3084j)

Input is a 256x256 data generated by
`input = numpy.random.rand(256,256)`
and the above result is part of the data generated by using this data(256x256) as input. Using this data(256x256), Matlab and torch.fft.fft2 output the same result

How torch.fft stores the real and imaginary parts of the result in a tensor of the same shape?

How can I use `torch.fft.fft2` to output the same result as `torch.fft`?

Comment: Can you add the input that you use to obtain the respective tensors?

Comment: You can convert complex FFT results to real using `abs` or `np.abs`.

Comment: Input is a 256x256 data generated by ```input = numpy.random.rand(256,256)```, and the above result is part of the data generated by using this data(256x256) as input. Using this data(256x256), ```Matlab``` and ```torch.fft.fft2``` output the same result.@dennlinger

Answer (score 0):

I was struggle in this for few days, then i try all parameters in **torch.fft.fft2**,finally i found set `norm='ortho'` make the same result with old pytorch **torch.fft** . Hope this will help you.